# **** 04:04:32 TPT10508: RDBMS error 3857: Cannot use value (or macro parameter) to match '<column_name>'

Tags: sql, teradata

> **** 04:04:32 TPT10508: RDBMS error 3857: Cannot use value (or macro parameter) to match '<column_name>'.

facing this issues while
executing tpt to load data from csv to Teradata DB. Could you please
help me in resolving this issue.

simple cast logic is used to convert data type from Varchar to decimal and timestamp(0).
and if i hardcode the value like `(cast(20.0) as decimal(12,2) )` its working fine.
Failure case `cast(column_nm) as decimal(12,2)` .

Comment: Can you share that part from your TPT script? Usually there's no need for an explicit cast, it's done implicitly to match the target column.

Comment: ,CAST(:actvt_amt as DECIMAL(12,2))
,CAST(CAST(:actvt_eff_dt as timestamp(0) FORMAT ''MM/DD/YYYYBhh:mi:ss'') as date FORMAT ''YYYY-MM-DD'')
,CAST(:src_load_dt_tm AS timestamp(0) FORMAT ''MM/DD/YYYYBhh:mi:ss'')
,CAST(:src_updt_dt_tm AS timestamp(0) FORMAT ''MM/DD/YYYYBhh:mi:ss'')

Comment: sually there's no need for an explicit cast, it's done implicitly to match the target column-- it actually worked for me. Thank you

Comment: In a TPT `APPLY` clause, the only valid use of `CAST` is to assign a datatype to the literal `NULL` value. You can, of course, use `CAST` within a (quoted) SQL statement supplied as an operator attribute.